# WebComponents.dev for Lightning Web Components: How to?

Tags: lightning-web-components, web-components, lwc-playground

We are now seeing the following message at the top of the [Lightning Web Components Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground):

> Playground will be retired on February 1, 2021. All saved projects
> will be permanently deleted at that time. Instead, try a third-party
> solution such as webcomponents.dev to edit and preview your components
> in a browser. We'll be publishing a blog soon with all the details.

Obviously there's an important blog entry pending.  The blog will probably get most of us up and running with the new recommended way of doing browser-based LWC futzing.

In the mean time, are there any trailblazing StackExchange contributors willing to initiate us (erstwhile) Playground fans on how to get started with [WebComponents.dev](https://webcomponents.dev/) + LWC?  Or similar tools we might consider using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blog is currently live on salesforce developers website

You can look into the below link for the details

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/11/ecosystem-innovation-with-lightning-web-components.html

You can visit the below link to create your web component

https://webcomponents.dev/create/lwc

You can also publish the lwc component as npm from there or share the component with other developers